# Can you use keyboard and mouse sharing in wayland?

Tags: keyboard, mouse

With each new ubuntu version I've tried to give wayland another chance. But one of the reasons I end up going back to xorg is the fact that Barrier does not seem to work properly under wayland.

Is there any alternative software that lets me share mouse and keyboard between two computers that runs under wayland?

Answer (score 2):

[rkvm](https://github.com/htrefil/rkvm) is independent of any display server.